# Drawing a grid for grass fire algorithm using jswing

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, robotics

Hi I want to implement grassfire algorithm using Java or Python . I would like to make a GUI application using Java Swing or Applet class. I am facing a problem and how to make a 2-D grid and then placing obstacles on the 2D grid pattern . Also I need to mark the starting and the ending cells. How should I implement it? Any naive ideas to implement it will be welcomed

Thanks

Comment: Your question very much sounds like a "programming novice" one, and the task you chose is a bit advanced, so maybe a good Java or Python course would turn out more helpful than Stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.